# Почему телеграм не отображает превью конкретно моей ссылки?

Tags: html, html5, seo, telegram

К примеру, когда я делюсь ссылкой на другие сайты, телеграм подхватывает и делает превью, однако в случае с моим веб-ресурсом такое не происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

OG использую:

```
<html lang="ru" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="path/to/photo.jpg?v=4">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="---"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="---">
<meta property="og:description" content="---">
```

Telegram Webpage bot:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и для сравнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случайным образом получилось разобраться. 
Проблема была в том, что использовалось одинаковое описание для следующих мета-тегов:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="---"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="---">
<meta property="og:description" content="---">
```

В этом случае телеграм просто не отображает превью. 
Решение: разное описание для og:site_name, og:title и og:description.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что проблема может быть в мета-теге `robots noindex`, который запрещает серверу Telegram информацию с вашего веб-сайта. Причём, если этот мета-тег используется, OG не начнёт работать до тех пор, пока сервер Telegram не просканирует ваш сайт после изменения тега.

Comment: хм, я не использовал подобных мета-тегов и даже robots.txt не использовал. Вряд ли бот не может сканить если нет файла robots.txt, но чтобы этот вариант откинуть, я перепроверю вечером.